# writefile with fs, nodejs and express

Tags: javascript, node.js, upload, base64

I'm trying to save an image on the server with fs.writefile and base64, it can write and save the image in the correct directory but the image is blank and says "no support this type of file".

my server function:

```
let base64 = '';
    let file = req.body.arquivo
    let reader = new FileReader()
    reader.onloadend = function(){
         base64 = reader.result
    }
    let img = base64.replace(/^data:image\/\w+;base64,/, "");
    let buffer = new Buffer(img, "base64")
    fs.writeFile(`./public${caminho}${nome}`, buffer, (err) => {console.log(err)});

    const candy = await Candy.create({
        nome: nome,
        doce: doce,
        caminho: caminho,
        tema: tema
    });

    return res.json(candy);
},
```

here is when I open the image in the directory that was saved:

[image]

Comment: Use this module base64-to-image

Comment: I put: let buffer = new Buffer.from(img, "base64-to-image") and in the console: TypeError [ERR_UNKNOWN_ENCODING]: Unknown encoding: base64-to-image

Comment: no i meant you should install base64-to-image module from npm [Documentation](https://www.npmjs.com/package/base64-to-image)

Comment: Errors such as: UnhandledPromiseRejectionWarning: Error: Missing arguments base64 string and / or path string required

Comment: UnhandledDocumentationReadingError? The documentation elraphty linked explicitly shows the function taking 2 parameters. And the error you get clearly states you forgot one of them... Also, to understand how to do with `fs` only, you can have a look at the [package's code](https://github.com/helensy/base64-to-image/blob/master/index.js).